# How to write hashCode method for a particular class?

Tags: java, class, character, hashcode, compareto

I'm trying to generate a hashCode() method for my simple class but i'm not getting anywhere with it. I would appreciate any help. I've implemented the equals() method, which looks as follows, and would also like to know if I need to implement compareTo() method. I've imported java.lang.Character to use character.hashCode() but it doesn't seem to work.

```
private class Coord{
    private char row;
    private char col;
    public Coord(char x, char y){
        row = x;
        col = y;
    }
    public Coord(){};

    public char getX(){
        return row;
    }

    public char getY(){
        return col;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object copy){
        if(copy == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Object entered is empty");
        }
        else if(copy.getClass()!=this.getClass()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Object entered is not Coord");
        }
        else{
            Coord copy2 = (Coord)copy;
            if(copy2.row==this.row && copy2.col==this.col)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance...

The comparTo() method that is giving me java.lang.Comparable casting error..

```
public int compareTo(Object copy){
        if(copy==null){
            throw new NullPointerException("Object entered is empty");
        }
        else if(copy.getClass()!=this.getClass()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Object entered is not Coord");
        }
        else{
            Coord copy2 = (Coord)copy;
            if(copy2.row==this.row && copy2.col==this.col){
                return 0;
            }
            else if(copy2.col < this.col){
                return -1;
            }
            else{
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

thanks...

Comment: I think [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java?rq=1) will help you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To implement hashCode, you override the default implementation from Object:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return row ^ col;
}
```

This isn't really an ideal hash, since its results are very predictable and it is easy for two different `Coord` objects to return the same value. A better hash would make use of the built-in `Arrays` class from `java.util` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html):

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[]{new Character(row), new Character(col)});
}
```

You can use this method to generate a pretty good hash with any number of fields.

To implement compareTo, you'll want your class to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

```
public class Coord implements Comparable<Coord>
```

Once you've done this, you can make compareTo take an argument of type `Coord` rather than type `Object`, which will save you the trouble of checking its type.

Comment: You don't need Java 7 if you use `Arrays.hashCode(Object[] args)` which has been in Java since 1.5

Comment: @durron597 I've also written a comparTo() method thatlooks like `public int compareTo(Object copy){
   if(copy==null){
    throw new NullPointerException("Object entered is empty");
   }
   else if(copy.getClass()!=this.getClass()){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Object entered is not Coord");
   }
   else{
    Coord copy2 = (Coord)copy;
    if(copy2.row==this.row && copy2.col==this.col){
     return 0;
    }
    else if(copy2.col < this.col){
     return -1;
    }
    else{
     return 1;
    }
   }
  }`
But I keep getting Coord cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable. May I know why?

Comment: @AdityaGore You should ask that in a separate question.

Comment: @durron597 Sorry about that. I've edited my question and added the additional content here. I don't know if two different posts for similar question would be advisable!!

Comment: You say `return row ^ col;` "isn't really an ideal hash, since ...it is easy for two different `Coord` objects to return the same value." I was reading an [article](https://crunchify.com/how-to-override-equals-and-hashcode-method-in-java/) and it says, "It is a popular misconception that hashCode provides a unique identifier for an object. It does not."  Could you elaborate on this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Hashcode is an `int` (32 bits), your data is `char` (16 bits), so I would probably just do:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (row << 16) + col;
}
```

This puts the bits from `row` in the first 16 bits and the bits from `col` in the last 16 bits, so this is a [**perfect** hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) for this class.

If you refactor your class to be more complicated, I recommend using nullptr's answer.

---

To use `Comparable`, do:

```
public class Coord implements Comparable<Coord>
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong, but you will never have collisions; the possible objects seem to map 1-to-1 with the possible hashCodes.  And this should be really fast, so this is an awesome answer.

Comment: Yep.  "Fairly unlikely" is understating it.  This is actually a perfect hash function for a pair of chars; two objects will have the same hash code if, and only if, they represent equal values.

Comment: @CoryKendall Well, remember, a `HashMap` uses modulus on the `hashCode()` value, it doesn't contain 2^32 possible cells. So for certain characters and moduluses and `HashMap` sizes, it will still have collisions. However, I agree I could have phrased it better :)

Comment: @CoryKendall I changed the wording to be more accurate ;)

Answer (score 5):

I found very valuable information concerning this topic and many other topics in the [Effective Java book, written by Joshua Bloch](http://uet.vnu.edu.vn/~chauttm/e-books/java/Effective.Java.2nd.Edition.May.2008.3000th.Release.pdf). Look at page 45 for further information about hashCode() and equals().

If you use an IDE like Eclipse you can let it generate the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods. For your class the result would be:

```
class Coord implements Comparable<Coord> {

    private char row;
    private char col;

    public Coord(char x, char y) {
        row = x;
        col = y;
    }

    public Coord() {
    };

    public char getX() {
        return row;
    }

    public char getY() {
        return col;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + col;
        result = prime * result + row;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Coord other = (Coord) obj;
        if (col != other.col)
            return false;
        if (row != other.row)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int compareTo(Coord param) {
        // Implementation according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: I know this is a pretty typical implementation, but it's got some tricky numerical downsides.  If you have just two components you're hashing - such as here - and they both have the same value (not an unusual occurence), this is equivalent to `32*hash+offset` which has 5 less bits of entropy than your source hash.  Not ideal.

Answer (score -1):

similar to durron597's answer, you can try this if your input is bounded by char (between 0 and 65535 )

```
public int hashCode(){
   return row * 100000 + col;
}
```

Comment: This answer is redundant, and while it's correct, it's tricky because it includes a non-obvious magic number that only works because it's greater than or equal to 65536